# How to modify Shortcode Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, carousel, shortcode

I'm using a by-default carousel in Wordpress and it's code is

```
[carousel arrows="display" buttons="display" caption="display"]
```

[panel][/panel]
[/carousel]

I wanna adjust the Width and Height of it. So, can anyone tell me how i should modify it so that i can make it custom with width and Height.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the function responsible for the creation of the shortcode in the plugin files. It should be near something like this

```
add_shortcode("carousel", "name_of_the_fuction");
```

After you find the function responsible for the shortcode you will need to add something like this:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "width"  => default,
    "height" => default,
), $atts));
```

Comment: Where to find this function in which .php file

Comment: The functions.php file is in the root of your theme folder.